# What is this image layout style referred to? Can it be achieved easily with flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Below I have attached an image of a layout of photos. I can't seem to get the name for this format of image layout. Is it flexbox? grid layout? Additionally, I wanted to know if it was possible to have this image layout format created through flutter with existing assets.

[image]

Comment: Try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view#-installing-tab-)** package.

In the pubspec.yaml , add the following dependency:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: any
```

In your library , add the following import:

```
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
```

**Example:**

```
  StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  itemCount: 8,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: new Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text('$index'),
        ),
      )),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
),
```

> Use it like [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Constructors** :

The **[StaggeredGridView](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/StaggeredGridView-class.html)** follow the same constructors convention than the **[GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)**.
There are two more constructors: `countBuilder` and `extentBuilder`. These constructors allow you to define a builder for the layout and a builder for the children.

**Tiles** :

A **[StaggeredGridView](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/StaggeredGridView-class.html)** needs to know how to display each tile, and what widget is associated with a tile.

A **[tile](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_staggered_grid_view/latest/flutter_staggered_grid_view/StaggeredTile-class.html)** needs to have a fixed number of cell to occupy in the cross axis. For the extent in the main axis you have **03 options**:

1. You want a fixed number of cells => use `StaggeredTile.count`.
2. You want a fixed extent => use `StaggeredTile.extent`.
3. You want a variable extent, defined by the content of the tile
   itself => use `StaggeredTile.fit`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you wouldn't want to use any package (sometimes this is a healthy solution), you could easily achieve what you want by combining `Columns`, `Rows` and `Expanded` Widgets using `flex` property to define what percentage of the Main Axis you would want your different Widgets to occupy (in your case, the images to be displayed).